# Inverse of a specific upper-triangular matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

> $$
> A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 &  &  &  &  \\
>      &  1 &  & (-1)  &  \\
>      &   &  1 &   &  \\
>      & (0) &  & \ddots &  \\
>      &  &  &  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & -1 & -1 & \dots  & -1 \\
>     0 &  1 & -1 & \dots  & -1 \\
>     0 &  0 &  1 & \dots  & -1 \\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Prove that $A$ is invertible, and find $A^{-1}$

**What I did so far:**

My idea was to use the Gauss Elimination Method to find the reduced echelon form of $A$ by performing (left-multiplication) some elementary operations (permutation of lines, multiplying a line by a scalar, ...) $T_1, T_2,\dots, T_k$ so that $T_1T_2\dots T_kA=I_n$ which I can easily calculate by performing the operation on $I_n$

From this, we find $A^{-1} = T_1T_2\dots T_k$

I found two methods:

**Method 1:**

Add line $L_2$ to $L_1$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2&-2&(-2)\end{bmatrix}$

Add line 2$L_3$ to $L_1$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-4&(-4)\end{bmatrix}$

Add line 4$L_4$ to $L_1$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&(-8)\end{bmatrix}$

$\vdots$

Add line $2^{i-1}L_i$ to $L_1$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&(-2^i)\end{bmatrix}$

Then $A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & \dots  & 2^{n-2} \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & \dots  & 2^{n-3}\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \dots  & 2^{n-4}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

**The Problem:**

For our class, this is not considered as a valid proof. I have to be as rigorous as possible. And I have to prove that these operations can reduce the matrix.

Comment: How did you find the inverse without calculating it?

Comment: Sounds like you have a candidate $B$ for $A^{-1}$. The next step is to write it down, and prove that $BA=AB=I$.

Comment: I think to be rigorous you need to prove your result for the base case of a $2\times 2$ matrix, then use induction to prove it for an $n\times n$ matrix.